# I have trouble in number theory. A simple question...

Tags: elementary-number-theory

Let $a, b, c, d$ be non-zero integers with $\gcd(a, b) = \gcd(c, d) = 1$.
 Show that

$$\gcd(ac, bd) = \gcd(a, d) \cdot \gcd(b, c)$$

I have awful time in number theory. :< even have no idea to solve this.

Need your help!

Comment: Can you use the fundamental theorem of arithmetic?

Comment: will the fundamental theorem help? I think I can use.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you can use the fundamental theorem of arithmetic, then this can be done in a very conceptual way by thinking of integers as "bags" of prime numbers. Take a look at these Venn diagrams.

[image]

[image]

[image]

[image]

The FTA allows you to think of a number as just a collection of prime numbers. Above, I've drawn Venn diagrams representing the numbers $a,b,c$ and $d$ as sets of primes. Operations like gcd and multiplication (and others, like lcm and division) then correspond to set theoretic operations like unions and intersections. I won't prove anything I say below, I'll let you think about it for yourself.

When you multiply two numbers, you take the union of those two collections. For example, $4=2\cdot2$ and $15=3\cdot5$, thus $4\cdot15=2\cdot2\cdot3\cdot5$. Thus, in diagrams (2) and (3) above, the product $ac$ corresponds to the union of the regions $a$ and $c$.

The GCD of two numbers is similar to the *intersection* of the two corresponding sets. For example, $60=5\cdot3\cdot2\cdot2$ and $24=3\cdot2\cdot2\cdot2$, so the GCD is equal to $3\cdot2\cdot2$. We take the largest possible collection of prime numbers that is inside *both* of the numbers $60$ and $24$. Thus, in the first diagram above, I've represented the gcds of the various numbers as their intersections.

You'll notice that $a, b$ and $d, c$ have no intersections. This is because $\gcd(a, b)=\gcd(c, d)=1$. To say that two numbers have a gcd of $1$ is to say that the intersection of the corresponding two lists of prime numbers is empty.

Now, we can bring all of this together to prove what we wanted to prove. Look at the last diagram. The blue region is equal to the union (ie, product) of $\gcd(a, d)$ and $\gcd(b, c)$. But it's also equal to the intersection (ie, gc) of $ac$ and $db$, the red and green regions from the other two diagrams. Thus, those two numbers are equal.

Answer (score 1):

Write $\,(x,y):=\gcd(x,y).\,$ Note $\,(j,kn) = (j,k(n,j))\,$ by RHS $=(j,kn,kj) = (j,kn),\,$ thus

$$\begin{align}
(ac,bd) 
&= (ac,\,(\color{#c00}{b,a}c)(\color{#0a0}d,a\color{#0a0}c))\ \ \text{by applying above twice}\\[.2em]
&= (ac,\,(b,c)\ (d,a))\quad\ {\rm by}\ \ (\color{#c00}{b,a})=1=(\color{#0a0}{d,c})\\[.2em]
&= (b,c)(d,a)\ \ \text{since it divides }\, ac,\ {\rm by}\,\ (d,a)\mid a,\ (b,c)\mid c
\end{align}$$

Comment: that make a sense for me. thank you!